# YouTube API V3 difficulties while fetching top channels based on specific country

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-channels

I want to fetch top channels (i.e top 10,100,150 channels) based on their subscribers and view count for specific country, How can I do that?

I have tried to use

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search
```

but there is not any way found to fetch/search top YouTube channels with this API call, and not other way found for my need

Note: Tried regionCode parameter but that's not for filter the channels it fetching based on videos viewing in specific country

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: Perhaps this can help: https://github.com/soodoku/tuber/issues/24

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is not currently possible with this api.

[search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)

Supports searching on a [single region code](https://www.iso.org/iso-3166-country-codes.html)

[image]

The Q paramater only does a fulltext search on the description and title of the video

[image]

There is no way to sort on either channels or subscribers.

Comment: Thank you so much @DaImTo
Actually about regionCode and q parameter I know but that won't workable in my case, thank you so much for your answer I will find another way to work around